# Google Apps Script return date between a range of dates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, while-loop

I have an array of dates. I want to return the dates between January 01, 2022 and December 31, 2022.

When I run the cut below, it doesn't return anything. This is one of many different loop variations I've tried to no avail. Please help TIA

```
var start = new Date(2022, 0, 01); //returns Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var end = new Date(2022, 11, 01); //returns Sat Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var arr = [Fri Dec 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 17 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 24 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
           ...](**output** NOT the actual script)
for(var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i] >= start && arr[i] <= end){
      Logger.log(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your script, I couldn't understand the value of `arr`. Because in your script, when you save the script, an error occurs. So I'm worried that your actual script is different from your showing script. If each value of `arr` is the string type like `Fri Dec 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`, please enclose it using the double or single quotes.

  - If my guess of your script is not correct, please provide your actual script.
- In order to compare the date, I think that this thread will be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/7108653)

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
var start = new Date(2022, 0, 01); //returns Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var end = new Date(2022, 11, 01); //returns Sat Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var arr = [
  "Fri Dec 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Dec 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Dec 17 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Dec 24 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Dec 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Jan 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Jan 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
  "Fri Jan 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)",
];
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  if (new Date(arr[i]).getTime() >= start.getTime() && new Date(arr[i]).getTime() <= end.getTime()) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- Related thread

  - [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/7108653)

Answer (score 0):

What [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned is correct, it should be a string in your array and missing quotes then you can do

```
arr.filter(dates => new Date(dates) >= start && new Date(dates) <= end );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out thanks for your input. The problem was I needed to set arr[i] to new Date(arr[i]). Below is the updated code.

```
var start = new Date(2022, 0, 01); //returns Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var end = new Date(2022, 11, 01); //returns Sat Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2022
var arr = [Fri Dec 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 17 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 24 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Dec 31 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time), 
           Fri Jan 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
           ...](**output of the array** NOT the actual script)
for(var i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){
   var arrI = new Date(arr[i]);
   if(arrI >= start && arrI <= end){
      Logger.log(arrI);
   }
}
```